# Unable to add simultaneous calculated column in kendo grid MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, dojo, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented kendo grid inline editing in my application. I have columns percentage and percentage amount in my grid which is calculated based on base amount.

I want that when user change the percentage then percentage amount should be calculated automatically. Also, when user change the percentage amount then percentage should be calculated automatically.

I have created this [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iJIJOL/5) to show the implementation.

Below is the code I am using currently:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button onClick="reset()" class="k-button">Reset test data</button>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>

function setTestData(){
    var testData = [
      {ID: 1, Value: "TEST1", BaseAmount: 500, IncreasePercentage: 10, IncreaseAmount: 50},
      {ID: 2, Value: "TEST2", BaseAmount: 500, IncreasePercentage: 10, IncreaseAmount: 50},
      {ID: 3, Value: "TEST3", BaseAmount: 500, IncreasePercentage: 10, IncreaseAmount: 50},
      {ID: 4, Value: "TEST4", BaseAmount: 500, IncreasePercentage: 10, IncreaseAmount: 50},
      {ID: 5, Value: "TEST5", BaseAmount: 500, IncreasePercentage: 10, IncreaseAmount: 50}  
    ];
    localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(testData);
}

function reset(){
    setTestData();
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    if(localStorage["grid_data"] == undefined){
        setTestData();
    }

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
          create: function(options){
            var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
            options.data.ID = localData[localData.length-1].ID + 1;
            localData.push(options.data);
            localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
            options.success(options.data);
          },
          read: function(options){
              var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
              options.success(localData);
          },
          update: function(options){
            var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);

            for(var i=0; i<localData.length; i++){
              if(localData[i].ID == options.data.ID){
                localData[i].Value = options.data.Value;
              }
            }
            localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
            options.success(options.data);
          },
          destroy: function(options){
            var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
            for(var i=0; i<localData.length; i++){
                if(localData[i].ID === options.data.ID){
                    localData.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
            options.success(localData);
          },
        },
        schema: {
          model: {
            id: "ID",
            fields: {
              ID: { type: "number", editable: false },
              Value: { type: "string", editable: false },
              BaseAmount:{type: "number" , editable: false},
              IncreasePercentage:{type: "number"},
              IncreaseAmount:{type: "number"}
            }}
        },
        pageSize: 20
    });

    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        pageable: true,
        height: 500,
        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
        columns: [
          { field: "ID", width: "100px" },
          { field: "Value", width: "100px"},
          { field: "BaseAmount", width: "150px"},
          { field: "IncreasePercentage", width: "150px"},
          { field: "IncreaseAmount", width: "150px"},
          { command:  ["edit"], width: "150px" }
        ],
        editable: "inline",
    }).data("kendoGrid");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected Behaviour:

1. BaseAmount=500, Percentage(Entered By User)=10, PercentageAmount(Auto Caluclated)=50
2. BaseAmount=500, Percentage(Auto Caluclated)=10, PercentageAmount(Entered By User)=50

I am using Kendo MVC grid but I cant create dojo for the same so I am providing jquery API. Is there a way out to add two simultaneous calculated column in kendo grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to changes on your datasource with the `change` event :

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  change: function(e) {
  // only triggered when the item changes
  if (e.action !== 'itemchange') {
    return;
  }

  if (e.field === 'IncreasePercentage') {
    $.each(e.items, function(i, item) {
      // calling item.set also triggers the change event, so we need to prevent infinite loops
      var newIncreaseValue = item.BaseAmount * item.IncreasePercentage/100;
      if (item.IncreaseAmount !== newIncreaseValue) {
        item.set('IncreaseAmount', newIncreaseValue);
      }
    });
  } else if (e.field === 'IncreaseAmount') {
    $.each(e.items, function(i, item) {
      // calling item.set also triggers the change event, so we need to prevent infinite loops
      var newIncreaseValue = 100 * item.IncreaseAmount / item.BaseAmount;
      if (item.IncreasePercentage !== newIncreaseValue) {
        item.set('IncreasePercentage', newIncreaseValue);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

There are various events that you can use depending on your needs; either on the datasource itself (like my example), or on the grid itself.

- Events on the datasource: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events
- Events on the grid: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this solution will not work. This will change the percentage when user press on "Update" button on grid. But I want to achieve the logic on change of percentage or percentage amount before pressing Update button. Is there a way out for this?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment. It will work before the update button is clicked, but only when the change event for the numeric textbox is triggered (and thus only if enter is pressed, of if it loses focus).